# Wavenet: Input a .txt which holds sentence prefixes but which are not synthesized and to be chosen as corresponding single filenames

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have a python code in which I work with the Wavenet API from Google.
I got a .txt-file as my SynthesisInput.
This .txt-file consists of several sentences.
Every sentence has a prefix which is formated like this: "questionsID_speaker_snippetNumber" for example "a1_bou_1".

Here is an extract from the input .txt-file

```
a1_bou_1: I don't try to think about it too much.
a1_bou_2: Are harming our planet.
a1_bou_3: There's no peace in sight.
a1_bou_4: Troubling topics.
a1_kat_1: I am concerned.
a1_kat_2: There is war in my country.
a1_ole_1: The recent things.
a1_ole_2: That happened to the world.
```

I need a code which synthesizes those sentences, but not the prefixes. I also want that every new sentence will be outputted as a single audio file named like the corresponding prefix in the .txt-file + a language name and code abbreviation (in my case AU-B)...

Any hints on how this can be achieved? Maybe with another input file format that can "overread" the prefixes or by transforming the input-.txt?

Here is my code which synthesizes the input-.txt into separate audiofiles named as desired but *with* the prefixes:

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'wavenet_tts.json'

client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="en-AU",
    name="en-AU-Wavenet-B"
)

audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    speaking_rate=0.8,
    pitch=-2.0,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100
)

filepath = '/file/path/for/input.txt'
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    sentences = [line.strip() for line in f]

for sentence in sentences:

    prefix = sentence[0:8]
    
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=sentence)
    response = client.synthesize_speech(
        input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
    )

    outputPath = "/my/output/patch/"
    with open(outputPath+f"{prefix}_AU-B.wav", "wb") as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content from AU-B written to file')
```

Comment: not familiar with the api, but have you tried to replace `texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=sentence)` by `texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=sentence.split(':')[1])` ...removing the prefix before calling the api?